Java : MIME type may not contain reserved characters<EOL>?
Hi I am using spring version 5.2.25.RELEASE
I am trying to call an api to upload file ,however i get below error in response
Note : I already added contentType as multipart/form-data
headers.add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
FileSystemResource fileResource = new FileSystemResource(file);
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("data", fileResource);

Below error I am getting in response.
500 : "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: MIME type may not contain reserved characters?at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371)?at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:234)?at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)?at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)?at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:243)

The exception message looks related to database storage.

I'd show more of your upload code

actually in further it says Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MIME type may not contain reserved characters?at org.apache.http.util.Args.check(Args.java:36)Even i am passing correct content type.
